# Numpy/Scipy with masks and RGB images

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a mask for an RGB image using skikit learn. I want to create a mask selecting only pixels which are equal to [0,10,0], ie 10 on green channel. And then show only those pixels. This should be straight-forward, akin to http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html, but I'm struggling.

If image is a loaded jpg, I can do

```
mask = image == [0,10,0]
image = image[mask]
viewer = ImageViewer(image)
viewer.show()
```

However, I get:

```
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

If I then print(mask), I realise that instead of a series of True and False for each pixel, I'm getting:

```
[[ True False  True]
  [ True False  True]
  [ True False  True]
  ..., 
  [ True False  True]
  [ True False  True]
  [ True False  True]]
```

Note that the 1st pixel in my image is black. So it appears what it's doing is comparing [0,0,0] with [0,10,0], and instead of raising False, it raises True,False,True.

This then appears to fail as a mask, because I have 3 masks for each pixel, I suppose!

Does anyone know a simple way to get this masking working with RGB images?

Thanks

Comment: What are the dimensions of your `image` array, does it match the shape of (n, 3)?

Comment: Nope it's (276, 274, 3)

Comment: How are you planning to use the mask to show the show those specific pixels? Because after masking, you won't have that 2D format of height and width.

Comment: Good point, but surely 'camera' in the example at http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html is x,y, and they successfully mask that using a mere series of True and False successfully? I'm unsure why changing from x,y to x,y,3 would stop this process from working...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could get that `2D` mask with ALL reduction along the last axis -

```
mask = (image == [0,10,0]).all(-1)
```

Then, `image[mask]` would be `(N,3)` shaped array of only `[0,10,0]` values, where `N` is number of pixels which were of that specific RGB triplet.

So, the step(s) to using `mask` to show the masked image or overlay would depend on the viewer.

---

For an in-situ edit in the image, such that we would mask out everything that's not of that specific RGB triplet, we could multiply with the mask -

```
image *= mask[...,None]
```

Or create a copy with a choosing mechanism using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
image_overlayed = np.where(mask[...,None], image, 0)
```

To get a `3D` mask (if that's what needed with viewer), we could replicate the mask along the channels as well -

```
np.repeat(mask[...,None],3,axis=2)
```

Comment: Couldn't you also do `image * mask[...,None]` to preserve the shape and allow use of `ImageViewer`?

Comment: Damn you're fast :P

Comment: @James True pixels image of shape (276, 274) or (276, 274,3)?

Comment: @James Use : `np.repeat(mask[...,None],3,axis=2)`. Edited post.

Comment: You could also just do `mask = (image == [0,10,0]).all(-1, keepdims = True)`

Comment: Not sure you want that @James.  If the number of "true" values is different in each row/column you'll end up with a ragged array that will cause problems

Comment: @James A mask would be spread randomly across the image ( in a general case). We don't have any information of any block, i.e. no high level image block info. The problem you are describing would involve a lot more than just masking. So, maybe post a new question on it.